# My laptop screen has a purple tint. How to fix it?

Tags: graphics, 18.04, amd-graphics, colors

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. My graphics card is AMD Radeon R3 Graphics.

This a screenshot of my screen.

[image]

Clearly the blue circle appears purple. Why is it happening and how to solve it?

My system is thoroughly updated and upgraded.

Or is it that I am actually color blind?

Comment: Does [this blue color test page](http://www.maccetera.com/screen/b.html) look blue or purple on your laptop screen?

Comment: It looks purple

Comment: Is the Night Light mode turned on in **Settings > Devices > Display**? If so, does turning it off fix it?

Comment: Yes night mode is turned on, checking it turning off.

Comment: The little half-moon icon in the upper right indicates active night mode. Just my two cents.

Comment: I didn't notice that :-)

Comment: Wait... you posted a screen shot to show us the color of your screen? This is the one time you are allowed to use a camera to take a picture of your screen, screenshots are going to be rendered by our computers as completely normal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since version 3.24, **Gnome** has a built-in blue light filter called **Night Mode** (AKA *Night Light*). It is now almost a proven fact that exposure to blue light in night-time disrupts our sleep pattern. Night Mode is there for that reason: to limit your exposure to both bright and blue light from the screen. It works by applying a red hue upon screen. So when it is turned on, blue color may look purple (this is the case here, see comments on the question).

Go to **Settings > Devices > Display**. There you can customize **Night Mode** by setting activation time or controlling red-level. Or you can disable the feature altogether.

[image: screenshot]

You can also change it [through commmand line](https://askubuntu.com/a/1088653/349837).

Comment: Although not related I am always curious about it? How to pronounce "Gnome"? Is it like "Go" for "Godzilla" and "no" for "necklace" pronounced one after another quickly? Like "Gonome"?

Comment: @Sonevol https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=892670

Comment: It's worth noting (preferably in the answer) that Night Mode is there for a reason: to limit your exposure to both bright and blue light from the screen, both of which [are thought to cause sleeping problems](https://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/blue-light-has-a-dark-side). Sure, disabling it is an option, but people should be made aware of the potential downsides of disabling it.

Comment: And it rests your eyes. Without wearing properly coated glasses it damages your eyes.

Comment: @Sonevol “…it damages your eyes” [ [Citation needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_needed) ]