# The color is wrong when using NVIDIA driver with HDMI

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, hdmi

My Ubuntu Desktop has the problem like picture as below:

[image: Color wrong]

The color should be blue but I got violet.

Installed NVIDIA driver:

```
NVIDIA-SMI 430.09       
Driver Version: 430.09
CUDA Version: 10.1
```

Ubuntu version: `19.04`, but the problem also happened with Ubuntu `18.04`.

GPU is a GeForce GTX 1060 3GB. It's working well on Windows 10. No issues.

Comment: Maybe it's caused by gnome's night light? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088650/gnome-night-light-setting-from-the-command-line